# How can I add BCC while sending an email from Open Cart?

Tags: php, email, opencart

Here is my code

```
$mail = new Mail($this->config->get('config_mail'));
$mail->setTo($customer_email);
$mail->setFrom($this->config->get('config_email'));
$mail->setSender($this->config->get('config_name'));
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setHtml($html);
$mail->setText(html_entity_decode($html, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->send();
```

I would like to add some BCC which will be dynamic, like from some modal pop up I am having all those emails with comma separated, which I will explode it and using a foreach or a for loop I would like to add those emails in BCC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in opencart > 2.0

first in system/library/mail.php file

find :

```
   public $parameter = '';
```

and add this code after :

```
    public $bcc= '';
```

then add this code to line 30

```
public function setBcc($bcc) {
    $this->bcc = $bcc;
}
```

find :

`$header .= 'Return-Path: ' . $this->from . $this->newline;`

add this after that

```
$header .='BCC: '. $this->bcc;
```

then in your code call

```
$mail->setBcc("yourBccList");
```

Comment: Code doesn't give any error but i am not getting on the email add i have added as BCC.

Comment: Thanks Buddy . . . .

Comment: not terribly important but the property `$bcc` should be `protected` according to the design pattern of Opencart's `mail` class.

Comment: If you choose to make it `public` you can skip the function altogether and just write `$mail->bcc = "yourBccList"` in your code

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
 $mail->setTo('Confidential Recipients <' .$config->get('config_email').'>');
 $mail->setCc($config->get('config_email_cc'));
 $mail->setBcc($email);
 $mail->setFrom($config->get('config_email'));
 $mail->setSender($config->get('config_store'));
```

Comment: Doesn't works for me.  i am using the version  2.0.1.1